# Plant identification: dwarf pine and spruce?

Tags: identification, shrubs, landscaping

Background: Asking for help with identifying a few more plants that we have now removed. Now that we have taken more interest in the plants around the house, we have a bit of remorse that we perhaps went too hastily in removing some of these overgrown, neglected plants when we moved in.

**Plant 1** ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYFMs.jpg)): some kind of dwarf pine?

[image: Plant 1]

**Plant 2** ([large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1TTX.jpg)): spruce?

[image: Plant 2]

For scale, they look like this together:

[image: Together]

Comment: I'm guessing the first one is a juniper or something in the Cupressaceae family.

Comment: Do the needles bend or break when you bend them? Do they have a sharp point? Is the trunk bark smooth? I've been looking at this and similar, which talk about the differences between various trees: https://mrtreeservices.com/blog/tell-difference-spruce-fir-pine-trees/

Comment: Unfortunately we burned the debris, but I remember that the needles were somewhat flexible and not very sharp.

Comment: The second one could be either a spruce or a fir. Not sure if anyone can ID them any more specifically than that with such limited evidence.

Comment: @csk Yeah, I know. We acted a bit impulsively and ignorantly, overwhelmed by how everything was out of control and how mice and roaches were coming out of the dense foliage. Seeing the flowering and the wonders a little bit of pruning can do, we are now curious what plant choice the previous owner had for the different areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Plant 1

It is hard to guess without closer look to the foliage, so I am going to split my pick:

- Juniperus 70%
- Chamacyparis 15%
- Thuja 15%

This reason that I favor juniperus is that many plants of that species have that gorgeous "windswept" look, the look seen on the original photo.

## Plant 2

[Picea abies 'Nidiformis'](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=c383)

Well-known and in demand dwarf cultivar of picea.

Comment: Thanks! I found the same picture for Picea abies 'Nidiformis' ("Norway spruce"), which looked very similar, hence my guess for some kind of spruce. But I don't know if there are any variant of fir as @csk mentioned that may also have a similar look.